# We cannot log on shared folder on the server

Tags: windows, networking

I am using Windows 10, I cannot connect to a shared network drive on another machine.

1. I can ping the machine.
2. I can remote desktop connect to the machine.
3. The machine is on the same subnet
4. My friend with the exact same laptop as me (and on the same network, same workgroup) can connect to the shared folder.

   - The machine I am trying to connect to and my friends machine can both see shared folders on my machine.
   - I also cannot see shared folders on the friends laptop.

When I select diagnose, Windows tells me nothing useful.

Answer (score 0):

Nice!

This is almost exactly the setup I give as an interview question to aspiring tech support candidates.

Basically, incoming requests are fine, but outgoing requests don't work for a specific protocol.

Usually the answer is the firewall for such a niche situation. Have you tried disabling all firewalls and trying?

Comment: Thank you ,all the firewall on the server are disabled

Comment: still not working? How many wifi/lan connections exist on your laptop? have you tried by disabling all VPN/adpaters and keep only one on? It seems like an issue in security/permissions or routing. You will need a more interactive support method to resolve the issue. do you still have the setup? can you draw a nice picture of the connections? I usually draw a -> b -> c ...etc

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a permission issue. Every time you access a shared folder you also send credentials. If you haven't pre-arranged to provide these credentials at the time of access then your login credentials are sent. You can verify this by trying to map the share with the NET USE command, if its a permission issue you will get "error 5 access denied". If so, then you have a couple of ways you can proceed. You can change the share permissions to allow you access, or you can map a drive letter and provide proper credentials when creating the mapped drive. I would choose both options, check the permissions on the shared folder and verify that you have permission, then map a drive letter to that shared folder and add proper credentials at that time. You are obviously working without a domain controller so your local machine will have to provide credentials every time you access something on the network.

If security is not a concern then you could share the folder granting full access to everyone. But this would not be my favored option.